# Web Forms Windows Authentication w/ Remote SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, windows-authentication, role-manager

I have a ASP.NET 4.0 web application that uses Windows Authentication against AD and a SQL Server for Role management.

Basically, I want all users who have an AD account to be able to access the application, but I want to further secure the app using roles in Sql Server. I do not want users to have to enter in their passwords for authentication.

Is it viable for me to check authentication in the Global Application_Start method, or should I be executing this code elsewhere?

Comment: This is too broad. There are too many possible answers, based on information you have not given us.

Answer (score 1):

`Application_Start` is only fired once when the Application itself is initialized. `HttpContext.Current.User` will contain details of the user making the HTTP request that caused IIS to initialize the application.

Instead use `Application_BeginRequest` which is raised for every incoming request, however ideally you should check authorization (not authentication) when the web-application intends to perform an action, not preemptively on every request.

Answer (score 1):

After further research I found "Application_AuthenticateRequest" which I think will serve my purposes of using Windows Authentication and Sql Server role configuration.

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // just grab the username without domain info
            string[] arrTmp = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');
            string username = arrTmp[arrTmp.Length - 1];

            // Create an array of role names
            List<String> arrlstRoles = new List<String>();

            // work-around
            if (username == "fakename")
                arrlstRoles.Add("Admin");

            // Add the roles to the User Principal
            HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(User.Identity, arrlstRoles.ToArray<String>());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`. Use `List<string>`. `ArrayList` is obsolete.

Comment: Thanks John, I switched out that.

Comment: You might also consider keeping the roles in AD as well.